# Open xml file with different extension using loadXMLDoc

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got a file with an extension of .abc which is an XML file and I am processing the XML using XSL.

I open an HTML page which loads the XML using loadXMLDoc like this:

```
xml=loadXMLDoc("Example.xml");  
xsl=loadXMLDoc("Example.xsl");
```

The problem is I need to open "Example.abc" not "Example.xml".  If I try:

xml=loadXMLDoc("Example.abc");

the page loads but with no data.

Is there a way I can load the .abc file?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear exactly what you are referring to here.

Do you mean the loadXMLDoc function that is introducted [here at w3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/dom_loadxmldoc.asp)?

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

I just tried playing around with this and it works perfectly well with any file extension for the .xml - one thing I did notice is that the browser was caching the html so that I had to close and reopen the page (when it was just on my desktop) to refresh the file name I had.

Could this be your issue?

Comment: When the file is served off IIS, then the `.abc` extension must be linked with a MIME type. If it isn't, the server will simply reply 404 even it the file is there. `.abc` is typically not configured.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Tomalak, wasn't aware of that, it's the sort of thing I usually hit, swear about, solve, then forget until the next time :)

Comment: Please [consider not linking to w3schools](http://w3fools.com) - it is a horrible site that just got so popular because of good SEO and with your rep your links are likely to lose `rel=nofollow` at some point and thus linking to them makes them even more popular in search engines. Besides that, linking to sites that teach people e.g. how to write horribly insecure code (look at their php/mysql examples) is bad in any case.

Comment: @ThiefMaster thanks for the comment - I agree, and almost edited the link away, but then paused, since my answer directly refers to their code and removing the link would move the answer towards plagiarism. Really the problem is that my answer was more a comment, and I'm tempted to delete it, except it just received an upvote, so was somehow actually useful to someone :( Feel free to edit or delete the answer :)

Comment: Just re-implement it nicely - you could improve it anyway (e.g. by making `xhttp` a local variable instead of leaking a global and possibly using a callback instead of a synchronous call).

Answer (score 0):

Did have the same problem. `XMLHttpRequest.get` requires a xml mime type.
To solve this, insert

```
if (xhttp.overrideMimeType)  xhttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
```

before the `xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);` line in the xsl file